# What is the most complex molecule we can manufacture without the help of proteins? (soft queston)

Tags: molecules

What is the most complex molecule we can manufacture without the help of proteins?

This isn't motivated by anything but curiosity about the state of chemical engineering. I realize “complexity” is a loaded term, so I'll defer to the judgment of the respondent: number of molecules, complex arrangement of bonds, or whatever other measure might be appropriate.

Comment: "Most complex" isn't well-defined.

Comment: Complex may not be well-defined, but that doesn't mean it isn't a useful term or that, in most cases, we know it when we see it. Big structures that are simple and repetitive wouldn't, I suggest, count. But even small structures with lots of chiral centres might.

Comment: Oh, and a trivial (and possibly ironic) answer might actually be "proteins" since they can occasionally be synthesised without the use of other proteins. Or possibly DNA/RNA which can be built in stages in the lab as a step towards the biological synthesis of non-natural proteins.

Comment: When I was taking freshman chem the book mentioned that a bowling ball is basically a cross-linked polymer network, so if a "complex molecule" is just a lot of atoms covalently bound together I am going bowling.

Comment: If we limit the answer to synthesized chemical substances with a single, definite chemical structure, and apply a generally accepted measure of complexity, then this is an answerable question. For synthetic organic chemists, vitamin B-12 used to be Mt. Everest.

Comment: @matt_black [They recently synthesized an entire protein using only D-amino acids and some clever synthetic techniques](http://www.pnas.org/content/111/32/11679.long) So if we managed to chemically synthesize mirror-image ribosomes (and associated folding proteins), could we argue that any resultant D-amino systems are purely chemical? Questions...

Answer (score 8):

I guess in the field of inorganic chemistry [polyoxometalates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyoxometalate) (POMs) are comparable with proteins in terms of structural complexity. Macroanionic POMs such as Keplerates $\ce{\{Mo132\}}$

[image]

are also capable of further self-assembly in diluted solutions, producing so-called "blackberries" [[1]](https://doi.org/10.1021/ja0685809) of a size of around $\pu{0.05 .. 0.1 \mu m}$:

[image]

Also, see the post [Measure the complexity of a molecule](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/76799/measure-the-complexity-of-a-molecule) and the corresponding paper [[2]](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.03460) of Prof. Lee Cronin, one of the most productive polyoxometalate chemist of current era.

1. Kistler, M. L.; Bhatt, A.; Liu, G.; Casa, D.; Liu, T. *J. Am. Chem. Soc.* **2007**, 129 (20), 6453–6460. DOI [10.1021/ja0685809](https://doi.org/10.1021/ja0685809).
2. Marshall, S. M.; Murray, A. R. G.; Cronin, L. [arXiv:1705.03460](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.03460) [q-bio.OT] **2017**.